# Dependencies problem installing mmrcn

Tags: opencv, image, cars

Hello i am trying to use ML techniques to identify cars in an image using opencv.

I have been following this tutorial : https://medium.com/@ageitgey/snagging-parking-spaces-with-mask-r-cnn-and-python-955f2231c400.
Great article and work.

I am trying it myself on my Rpi but i have been struggling a bit with dependencies problems during the installation of the dependencies of the main git library [Mask RCNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN). I have an import error when importing mrcnn.utils, each is exactly the same when importing imgaug. Error bellow.

Any suggestion on how to proceed.

thanks alot

Error message:

> ```
> import mrcnn.config
>  import mrcnn.utils
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/external/tifffile/tifffile.py:298:
> ```
>
> UserWarning: ImportError: No module named '_tifffile'. Loading of some
>   compressed images will be very slow. Tifffile.c can be obtained at
>   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/
>         "ImportError: No module named '_tifffile'. "
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mrcnn/utils.py", line 17, in 
>           import skimage.color
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/**init**.py", line
>   177, in 
>           from .data import data_dir
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/data/**init**.py",
>   line 18, in 
>           from ._binary_blobs import binary_blobs
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/data/_binary_blobs.py",
>   line 2, in 
>           from ..filters import gaussian
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/filters/**init**.py",
>   line 3, in 
>           from .edges import (sobel, sobel_h, sobel_v,
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/filters/edges.py",
>   line 17, in 
>           from ..restoration.uft import laplacian
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/restoration/**init**.py",
>   line 8, in 
>           from ._denoise import (denoise_tv_chambolle, denoise_tv_bregman,
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/restoration/_denoise.py",
>   line 6, in 
>           from ..restoration._denoise_cy import _denoise_bilateral, _denoise_tv_bregman
>         File "**init**.pxd", line 872, in init skimage.restoration._denoise_cy
>       ValueError: numpy.ufunc has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 112, got 124
>
> > > > ```
> > > > KeyboardInterrupt
> > > > ```
> > > >
> > > > import numpy
> > > >         import imgaug
> > > >             Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >               File "", line 1, in 
> > > >               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/imgaug/**init**.py", line 2,
> > > >         in 
> > > >                 from imgaug.imgaug import *
> > > >               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/imgaug/imgaug.py", line 18, in 
> > > >                 import skimage.draw
> > > >               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/**init**.py", line
> > > >         177, in 
> > > >                 from .data import data_dir
> > > >               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/data/**init**.py",
> > > >         line 18, in 
> > > >                 from ._binary_blobs import binary_blobs
> > > >               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/data/_binary_blobs.py",
> > > >         line 2, in 
> > > >                 from ..filters import gaussian
> > > >               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/filters/**init**.py",
> > > >         line 11, in 
> > > >                 from .thresholding import (threshold_local,
> > > >               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/filters/thresholding.py",
> > > >         line 8, in 
> > > >                 from ..transform import integral_image
> > > >               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/transform/**init**.py",
> > > >         line 1, in 
> > > >                 from .hough_transform import (hough_line, hough_line_peaks,
> > > >               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/transform/hough_transform.py",
> > > >         line 2, in 
> > > >                 from ._hough_transform import (_hough_circle,
> > > >               File "**init**.pxd", line 872, in init skimage.transform._hough_transform
> > > >             ValueError: numpy.ufunc has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 112, got 124
> > > >             `

Comment: Please edit your question to properly format your code to make it readable. `>` is used for quotes, not code. You just need to paste in your code, highlight it and click the `{}` icon to format it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial on how to work out the dependencies for a Python package:

https://blog.piwheels.org/how-to-work-out-the-missing-dependencies-for-a-python-package/

Comment: Thanks for the info however mrcnn does not seem to have a .so file inside /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mrcnn. Neither i have it on numpy : /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy

Comment: Check the list of other Python modules it depends on